# Lazy initialization of std::tuple elements

Tags: c++, c++14, lazy-initialization, stdtuple

I often use `std::aligned_storage` to specify an uninitialized class member. The typical example is an static_vector, which stores its elements within the structure.

However, I'm not completely sure what I should do when I want a `std::tuple` to be created *step by step*, initializing its members in an unspecified order at different points in time.

Would it be legal to create

```
std::tuple< std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Types),alignof(Types)>::type...>
```

and then reinterpret member reference as a `std::tuple<Types...>&`?

For example:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <memory>
#include <new>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template < class... Ts >
class uninitialized_tuple {
    public:
        using tuple_type   = typename std::tuple<Ts...>;
        using buffer_type =
            std::tuple<
                typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Ts),alignof(Ts)>::type...
            >;

        ~uninitialized_tuple() {
            destruct_helper<std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>>::erase(*this);
        }

        tuple_type& as_tuple() {
            reinterpret_cast<tuple_type&>(_storage);
        }

        bool valid() const {
            return _is_set.all();
        }

        template < size_t index, class... Args >
        void emplace( Args&&... args ) {
            using element_type = typename std::tuple_element<index,tuple_type>::type;
            new (&std::get<index>(_storage)) element_type( std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            _is_set.set(index);
        }

        template < size_t index >
        void erase() {
            using element_type = typename std::tuple_element<index,tuple_type>::type;
            if( _is_set[index] ) {
                std::get<index>(_storage).~element_type();
                _is_set.reset(index);
            }
        }

    private:
        template < class Seq >
        struct destruct_helper {
            static void erase( uninitialized_tuple& ) {}
        };

        template < size_t index, size_t... indices >
        struct destruct_helper<std::index_sequence<index,indices...>> {
            static void erase( uninitialized_tuple& value ) {
                value.erase<index>();
                destruct_helper<std::index_sequence<indices...>>::erase_one(value);
            }
        };

        buffer_type                _storage;
        std::bitset<sizeof...(Ts)> _is_set;
};
```

Comment: I don't think it would be legal.  AFAIK the size of the types `std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Types),alignof(Types)>::type...` can be larger than `Types...`, which would then give you unaligned access.

Comment: `as_tuple` looks like undefined behaviour to me.  You might want to tag this one as `language-lawyer`.

Comment: Certainly not valid. You can't alias `std::tuple<X>` with `std::tuple<Y>`.

Comment: @NathanOliver they are just completely unrelated types, so first off, it is a strict aliasing violation. But even disregarding that, there is nothing at all anywhere in the standard that `std::tuple<X>` might have any compatible layout with `std::tuple<Z>`.

Comment: You can not access an object that has never been created. Creating the element is not sufficient. Considering your code you do not need much help. You should better wrap each elements in a `union unitialized{ element_type value; char c='\0';uninitialized()=default;....~unitialized(){}}` and make you unintialized_tuple a... tuple => implement get, and specialize tuple_size and tuple_element.

Comment: Beware that placement `new` is like non-placement `new`. You are suppose to use the returned pointer to refer to the new object. You would then need to store these pointers and use those to refer to the elements. Perhaps you could make a `std::tuple<std::ref<Ts>...>` that refers to these dereferenced pointers. That's probably as close as you'll get. You could also consider a `std::tuple<std::optional<Ts>...>` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If this can't be done then, would the only option be constructing a new tuple with all the values in the `_storage` tuple? Something like:
`std::make_tuple(reinterpret_cast<std::tuple_element<indices,tuple_type>&>(std::get<indices>(_storage))...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing whatever is returned by `as_tuple()` is **undefined behavior** as it breaks the type aliasing rules. Please refer to  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast:

> Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an object of type DynamicType through a glvalue of type AliasedType, the behavior is undefined unless one of the following is true:
>
> - AliasedType and DynamicType are similar.
> - AliasedType is the (possibly cv-qualified) signed or unsigned variant of DynamicType.
> - AliasedType is std::byte, (since C++17)char, or unsigned char: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes.